# Extract the string between last two slashes

Tags: liquid

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to extract the content between to slashes in a liquid markup language.

Example:

I would have a string: /price/blue-cars/
and I wish to retrieve blue cars only from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to split the string into an array and get the last Item:

```
{{ "/price/blue-cars/" | split: "/" | last }}
```